# Change view properties after adding it as subview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I'm creating app where i'm using [pagedFlowView](https://github.com/kejinlu/PagedFlowView). I have custom view (*mainDetailV*) with ImageView as background and label on top. I'm using PagedFlowView delegate method to init all the views in it:

```
- (UIView *)flowView:(PagedFlowView *)flowView cellForPageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{

    mainDetailV = (MainDetailView *)[flowView dequeueReusableCell];

    if (!mainDetailV) {
        mainDetailV = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainDetailView"  owner:self    options:nil] lastObject];
        //mainDetailV.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
        mainDetailV.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    }

    return mainDetailV;
}
```

It's adding my view 5 times in pageFlowView.

I want to trigger some action, like changing alpha of label, on tapping the imageView, but i don't really know how to do this.

**My main question** is how can i change properties of this view after it's added to pagedViewController?

*Similar question*

- [Access properties of subview](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/15314-accessing-properties-of-subviews.html)

Comment: If you want to change properties when user interacts with your images you have to add `UIGestureRecognizer` on your `UIImageView`. Here is the link from apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html. BE CAREFUL, `UIImageView` has userInteraction disabled by default and you have to enable it in order to receive touches.

Comment: I never used PagedFlowView.But I guess there is a delegate method like "-(UIView *)flowView:(PagedFlowView *)flowView didTapOnCell" or something like this. In this method you should be able to access the cell. If not you could also add a gesture recognizer to the cell with a method as a target where you can access the sender of the gesture. This would be your cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the definition of mainDetailV?  It seems very strange to have this set as an Ivar

You should create mainDetailV as a local var and store it's contents in a mutable array just before you return it's value.  So:

```
- (UIView *)flowView:(PagedFlowView *)flowView cellForPageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{

    id mainDetailV = [flowView dequeueReusableCell];

    if (!mainDetailV) {
        mainDetailV = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainDetailView"  owner:self    options:nil] lastObject];
        //mainDetailV.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
        mainDetailV.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    }

    [usedViewControllers insertObject:mainDetailV atIndex:index];

    return mainDetailV;
}
```

where `usedViewControllers` is a NSMutableArray instance variable.

Then you can use the delegate method like so:

```
- (void)flowView:(PagedFlowView *)flowView didTapPageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
{
    MainDetailView *view = (MainDetailView *)[usedViewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(In addition to my comment)

I have looked into PagedFlowView delegate and there is a method

```
- (void)flowView:(PagedFlowView *)flowView didTapPageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
```

you can use the integer index to get the cell/page from the flow view that was tapped. If you have this one you can edit its properties.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea, thanks. But what i actually want is to change properties of mainDetailV not cell that contains mainDetailView.

Comment: In your code you set the mainDetailV as cell because you return one as a result in the - (UIView *)flowView:(PagedFlowView *)flowView cellForPageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index. So if you access your cell you also access your view

Comment: Well, then i need to change it's return value to MainDetailView* to access properties of my custom view.

Comment: No you dont have to as long as mainDetailV  is a subclass of uiview. But later you will have to cast the cell that you want to mainDetailV. The answer that you marked as correct shows how.